# phonegap ios plugin notificationEx CDVPlugin.h file not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I installed the phonegap plugin NotificationEx but I get this error when trying to compile:

> **CDVPlugin.h file not found.**

I'm using Xcode 4.5, cordova 2.2.0 and JQM 1.2.0

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I think this has been answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714600/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while installing the ShareKit plugin on Xcode 4.5, cordova 2.1.0 & JQM 1.2.0.
The problematic block was:

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPluginResult.h>
//#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>

#else
#import "CDVPlugin.h"
#import "CDVPluginResult.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"
#endif
```

What worked for me is commenting out the `#ifdef` line as well as commenting out the whole `#else` block.

Also, the `#import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>` line was already commented out in the source code that I downloaded with the plugin, so I didn't bother messing with that.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the whole #ifdef mess and

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

made my day :)